# Blas daxpy routine with matrices

Tags: matrix, blas

I am working on some matrices related problems in c++. I want to solve the problem: Y = aX + Y, where X and Y are matrices and a is a constant. I thought about using the daxpy BLAS routine, however, DAXPY according to the documentation is a vectors routine and I am not getting the same results as when I solve the same problem in matlab.

I am currently running this:

```
F77NAME(daxpy)(N, a, X, 1, Y, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to perform operation `Y=a*X+Y` it does not matter if `X',`Y` are 1D or 2D matrices, since the operation is done element-wise.

So, If you allocated the matrices in single pointers `double A[] = new[] (M*N);`, then you can use `daxpy` by defining the dimension of the vector as `M*N`

```
int MN = M*N;
int one = 1;
F77NAME(daxpy)(&MN, &a, &X, &one, &Y, &one);
```

Same goes with stack two dimension matrix `double A[3][2];` as this memory is allocated in sequence.

Otherwise, you need to use a `for` loop and add each row separately.